# Is it possible to modify layers of a pretrained convolutional neural network?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

What is the difference between evaluating a pretrained model and training one from scratch?

And if I want to add some layers to a pretrained model, is that possible? I am assuming I will have to train it again, but will it offer any advantage to utilize a pretrained model as opposed to starting from scratch?

Specifically I want to do this with the existing pytorch model of AlexNet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you want to use a pretrained model, all it means is that the model has been trained on a specific dataset and your using the weights learned by that network.In this case you may directly evaluate the model by giving it test images or else initialize your network with this weights and train a few additional layers.Pretrained models are almost always a better option than training a model from scratch, beacause these models have been trained on large number of images(Mostly on the imagenet dataset) there is good chance that the features learnt by the model may be useful in a different task.

training from scratch is training from random weights with your own dataset.
Hope this helps let me know if you have questions